# Set random color for a cgfill in external function

Tags: swift, random, colors

I have a rectangle and I want to fill it with a random color.

The function for returning the random color should be seperate.

This is my idea but it does not work out, I think because of the type? Do I need to do this with pointers?

```
func getRandomColor() -> CGColorRef {
    let color = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2])
    return color
}


func drawRect {
    // ...
    CGContextSetFillColorwithcolor(context,getRandomColor())
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func randomColorComponent() -> CGFloat
{
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
}

func randomColorRef() -> CGColorRef
{
    let red = randomColorComponent()
    let green = randomColorComponent()
    let blue = randomColorComponent()
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1).CGColor
}
```

and then somewhere in your drawRect use:

`CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, randomColorRef())`

Comment: Yes problem is then with this line:         CGContextSetFillColor(context, getRandomColor())

Normally you put in  the 4 values in there but I have a hard time fining out what I can use to get the values from the external function.

Comment: use `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, randomColor())` instead of `CGContextSetFillColor...`

Comment: weird I tried the same thing, only capitalized it different.. Thanks man! You saved my life